# how to write text at the accurate position of the background image in html mailer?

Tags: html, html-email

I have a table with rows and 4 column. In the first row i want a single td with image back ground (center) and some text on the center of  background image.I do this using

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="4"style="background-image: url(ribbon.png);background-position:center;background-repeat: no-repeat;text-align: center; vertical-position:bottom;color: white;font-weight: bold;">Analysis of Result</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now the back ground image is at the center of table cell(td). The text is in center of table cell not in the center of background image. Suggest me the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you find a new way to do this, as your current code's client compatibility will be mediocre at best. `vertical-position`, `text-align`, and all of your background css are poorly supported. As it is now, everyone who opens this email in Outlook will see 'Analysis of Result' in black bold Times New Roman at the top left of the table cell.

Get used to using `<td align="center" valign="middle">` to align text. Backgrounds can't be aligned in Outlook either, so I'd recommend designing around that.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

^ but really, try seeing if you can accomplish what you need through HTML attributes before trying CSS.